# I'm not sure my program is reading the file input I've asked it to

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

Here's my code that I have for an assignment that is supposed to read the file and add each integer into an ArrayList, split the list in half and put half in one list, half in another, sort the lists, then merge them, and print 50  of those integers from a random index. The file contains a large number of integers so that's why the index of the random is so high.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ProjectList 
{
    static ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> myList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> myList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    static int size = myList.size();
    static int size1 = myList1.size();
    static int size2 = myList2.size();

    public static void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner("numbers.txt");
        while (input.hasNextInt())
        {
            myList.add(input.nextInt());
        }
    }

    public static void dividePoint()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i++)
        {
            myList1.add(myList.get(i));
        }
        for (int i = size/2; i < size; i++)
        {
            myList2.add(myList.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void sort()
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
            {
                x = myList1.get(i);
                y = myList1.get(i + 1);
                if (x > y)
                {
                    myList1.remove(i);
                    myList1.remove(i + 1);
                    myList1.add(i, y);
                    myList1.add((i + 1), x);
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
            {
                x = myList2.get(i);
                y = myList2.get(i + 1);
                if (x > y)
                {
                    myList2.remove(i);
                    myList2.remove(i + 1);
                    myList2.add(i, y);
                    myList2.add((i + 1), x);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void merge()
    {
        while (size1 + size2 > 0)
        {
            int x = myList1.get(0);
            int y = myList2.get(0);
            if (x < y)
            {
                myList.add(myList1.get(0));
                System.out.println("Now removing " + myList1.get(0) + "from myList1.");
                myList1.remove(0);
            }
            if (y < x)
            {
                myList.add(myList2.get(0));
                myList2.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printRandom()
    {
           Random dice = new Random();
           int random = dice.nextInt(1000);
           for (int i = random; i < random + 51; i++)
           {
               System.out.println(myList.get(i));
           }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        readFile();
        dividePoint();
        sort();
        merge();
        printRandom();
    }
}
```

My problem arises in that whenever I run the main, nothing pops up. I have tried a couple solutions, such as making a new file and placing only about 15 integers in it so that the program didn't have as much to read, and also changing the file from its original ".dat" format to a ".txt" file, but those have not yielded successful results.

Comment: You are passing a string to your scanner object instead of a file object. Create a file object instead and pass to it, not a string. Please check the javadoc for scanner class for more detail.

Comment: Something like Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("numbers.txt"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)

According to the Java Scanner API, you can send it a file to read from. In your case, you are using-

```
new Scanner (String)
```

-which means you are reading through whatever String you pass it, rather than the file itself. Try something like-

```
File file = new File("yourFileName.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was already asked above, your problem was in fact, that you initialize Scanner via `new Scanner("numbers.txt")` instead of `new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"))`.

Also, I noticed, that you are trying to sort list after read. Your method looks like bad implemented [merge sort](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsMergesort/article.html). But if sorting is not your current task, you could just use `Collections.sort(myList)` instead of

```
dividePoint();
sort();
merge();
```

Comment: I'm aware of the sort methods already in Java, this was an assignment where we had a specific set of parameters that needed to be met. I'm not sure what my instructor had in mind, but I am grateful that you pointed out my mistake, I didn't even notice that I implemented that wrong